# Why does Heroku continue deployement even if rake assets:precompile fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

When deploying on heroku, heroku continues the deployement even if rake assets:precompiles fails.

Why is it the default behaviour? Is there a way to prevent heroku from deploying a version if rake assets:precompile fails? Thanks.

```
   -----> Writing config/database.yml to read from DATABASE_URL
   -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
          Running: rake assets:precompile
          rake aborted!
          The line was indented 2 levels deeper than the previous line.
          (in /tmp/build_3tgkcip2wq2qv/app/assets/stylesheets/master.css.sass)

          Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary
          (See full trace by running task with --trace)
          Precompiling assets failed, enabling runtime asset compilation
          Injecting rails31_enable_runtime_asset_compilation
          Please see this article for troubleshooting help:
          http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails31_heroku_cedar#troubleshooting
   -----> Rails plugin injection
          Injecting rails_log_stdout
          Injecting rails3_serve_static_assets
   -----> Discovering process types
          Procfile declares types      -> (none)
          Default types for Ruby/Rails -> console, rake, web, worker
   -----> Compiled slug size is 52.9MB
   -----> Launching... done, v163
```

Comment: Have you found a way to achieve this? Or a way to disable runtime asset compilation, so at least you'll notice it? Or some other way to automatically detect that asset compilation failed?

Comment: Any word or workaround on this?

Answer (score 1):

Because even with failed asset compilation the application would be able to serve requests that don't involve assets, f.x. serving REST xml or json requests.

Comment: That isn't a good reason. It's deploying a potentially (probably) broken application. It should at least be an option to fail the deploy. In fact it would be good to be able to have some API to do this so that other deployment tasks (and other buildpacks) could trigger deployment failure and prevent deployment.